# How can I recover my old Prime Video settings on iPad after returning from abroad?

Tags: ipad

I use the Prime Video app on iPad. I am normally based in Ireland. Over the summer I spent a few weeks in France. There were many videos that I could not watch in France that I could watch in Ireland. I know that this is because of licensing restrictions. This is not my problem. My problem is that I have now returned to Ireland--I've been back two weeks--and I cannot watch the videos here that I used to. My iPad is behaving as if it is still in France. How do I convince it that it is in Ireland, for this purpose?

In case it's relevant I will also note that my iPad actually changed its name (in Prime Video > Settings > My Account) when I was in France. Assume it used to be called 'X'. It is now called 'X 2'. It has not changed back to 'X'.

Comment: Go to `Settings app → General → Language & Region` and check if the Region is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried that and unfortunately the region is set correctly.

Comment: It's possible that your country/region setting for Amazon Prime has changed. Verify and set it correctly by following the instructions [here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201624360).

Comment: No joy. It did not work for me exactly as in those instructions, but I went to Manage Your Content and Devices > Preferences > Country/Region Settings, and the country is set correctly there.